# "If" function with ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I can't seem to make my formula work. Basically what I'm trying to archive here is to make the following function:

> =ImportXML("https://anywebsite.com/product/"&C3;"//*[@id='content']")

Working with IF function, I assumed it would work the following way:

> =IF(RegExMatch(D15;"#N/A"); ImportXML("https://anywebsite.com/product/"&C15;"//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div[2]/h1/span[2]/a[2]");"")

If the previous formula shows "#N/A" - it will run importXML and display results.

The ImportXML formula works just fine on its own.

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

Instead of REGEXMATCH use ISNA

## Explanation

- `REGEXMATCH(A1,"#N/A")` returns `#N/A` when `A1` value is `#N/A` instead of `TRUE`
- `ISNA(A1)` returns `TRUE` when `A1` value is `#N/A`